# Anvard HybridAuth Laravel implementation - Cannot redirect to an empty URL

Tags: laravel, hybridauth

Using Anvard's HybridAuth L4 package:

I have all this up and running and successfully attempted and completed a LinkedIn registration on my localhost.

The recordsets in user and profile tables have been inserted successfully but I then get an InvalidArgumentException: Cannot redirect to an empty URL

Any ideas? Is it because I haven't put into use the route: /anvard/endpoint? Where would I be specifying this? In the LinkedIn application details?

Clutching at straws I changed the MAMP port from 8888 back to 80 as I thought maybe it had something to do with the base_url in HybridAuth but that didn't do anything.

In the src/routes.php dir, it seems to get to

```
Log::debug('Anvard: login success');
Auth::loginUsingId($profile->user->id);
```

And then 
InvalidArgumentException

Cannot redirect to an empty URL.

Thanks a lot

Jon

Answer (score 2):

In the Anvard route file [anvard / src / Atticmedia / Anvard / routes.php]

Change
return Redirect::back(); 
to redirect to the actual route you want someone to go to.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make edit your `/app/anvar/config/routes.php` to look something like this:

```
<?php
return array(
    'index' => 'login',
    'login' => 'login/{provider}',
    'endpoint' => 'after/facebook',
/* note that endpoint can not be the same pattern as login
for example if I made it login/after it would go back to the login page with 'after' as $provider
*/
        );
```

Create a file in `app/storage/logs/` and name it hauth_debug_file.txt then
Add the following to your `/config/packages/anvard/hybridauth.php`

```
"debug_mode" => true,
"debug_file" =>"D:\www\Dev\bp4\app\storage\logs\hauth_debug_file.txt",
//change this path with yours
```

this will dump a lot of good info for debugging in the file, then you can share the file to help solve the problem. So your file would look something like this:

```
<?php
return array(

    // 'base_url' => URL::route(Config::get('anvard::routes.login')),

    'providers' => array (


        'Facebook' => array (
            'enabled' => true,
            'keys'    => array ( 'id' => 'yourr-key', 'secret' => 'your-secret' ),
            //'scope'  => Input::get('permission_scope','email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_likes, user_interests, user_location'),
        ),

        'Twitter' => array (
            'enabled' => false,
            'keys'    => array ( 'key' => '', 'secret' => '' )
        ),

        'LinkedIn' => array (
            'enabled' => false,
            'keys'    => array ( 'key' => '', 'secret' => '' )
        ),
    ),
    "debug_mode" => true,
    "debug_file" =>"D:\www\Dev\bp4\hauth_debug_file.txt",

);
```

Alternatively you can set this configurations via config::set in your /app/start/local.php
also in /anvard/src/Atticmedia/Anvard/routes.php I think it works better if you change `return Redirect::back();` to `return Redirect::to(Config::get('anvard::routes.endpoint'));`

I also had to edit Atticmedia/Anvard/Anvard.php around line 230 to

```
$profile = new $ProfileModel();
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $v) {
            $profile->$key = $v;
        }
        $profile = $this->applyAdapterProfileToExistingProfile($adapter_profile, $profile);
```